# Join 3 tables and display records even if missing value from 3rd table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join three tables with this query:

```
select *, max(working_dx.date_added), diagnosis_list.diagnosis as WorkingDiagnosis from working_dx 
    inner join ild on ild.id_incr=working_dx.pt_id
    inner join diagnosis_list on working_dx.dx_id = diagnosis_list.id
    group by pt_id";
```

I want all the records in ild table, even if no matching record in working_dx - if no match the value in WorkingDiagnosis would simply be blank.

The above query only gives me back records where working_dx.dx_id has a value.  How do I do the JOIN statements to give me back all the records even if blank.

Comment: use a `left join` to return where no record also : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html

Comment: which table do I left join?  If I left join both, I still only get 252 records and the ild table has 600 records. I changed query to get it FROM ild table and still only 250 records.

Comment: If you want all the records from `ild` then you need to select from that table and left join the other two on a common column. Your group by statement may also cause the others to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *, max(working_dx.date_added), 
(CASE WHEN diagnosis_list.id IS NULL THEN  "" ELSE diagnosis_list.diagnosis  END) as WorkingDiagnosis 
    FROM working_dx 
    INNER JOIN ild on ild.id_incr=working_dx.pt_id
    LEFT JOIN diagnosis_list on working_dx.dx_id = diagnosis_list.id
    GROUP BY pt_id;
```